# websphere not starting with error ADMU7704E

Tags: websphere

I created websphere server. I was able to launch my application with it. However after I enable the debugging , the server is not starting. I am getting the following error

"ADMU7704E: Failed while trying to start the Windows Service associated with
           server: server1; probable error executing WASService.exe"

On some sites a workaround was to delete server.pid file but I am not seeing any such files in the location.
Please suggest

Comment: Have you looked into the logs to see if there are any more detailed errors in there? How are you starting the server (command line, in a developer tool or as a windows service)?

Comment: I am trying to start the server from UI (start menu program->websphere) and its starting this as windows service

Comment: Also i have found a workaround. I need to restart my machine after each shutdown. I need to start and stop the server repeatedly so I am still having a tough time.

Comment: Are you shutting down the server before you try to start it again?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to test is to disable the WAS Windows service from Windows Services Panel and then try to start server using command line ie  startserver.bat  
You run this command from PROFILE_HOME/bin. if this starts fine, you can recreate the service using wasservicecmd 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21397335

If the manual startup fails , please check if any logs created under PROFILE_HOME/logs// Check for any error messages in SystemOut.log, SystemErr.log , native_stderr and native_stdout  logs.

PROFILE_HOME is home directory of WAS profile.

VG, opinions are my own and not those of my employer